# Netty ISO8583 decode contains persian characters on field 48.860

Tags: java, netty, iso8583

I am trying to decode Iso8583 that contains Persian characters in field 48 tag 860, but I faced and exception of `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

```
protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf byteBuf, List out) throws Exception {
    logger.info("decoding a new iso message: {}", byteBuf.readableBytes());

    if (!byteBuf.isReadable()) {
        logger.info("message is not readable");
        return;
    }
    byte[] bytes = new byte[byteBuf.readableBytes()];
    byteBuf.readBytes(bytes);

    try {
        final IsoMessage isoMessage = messageFactory.parseMessage(bytes, isoHeaderLength);
        if (isoMessage != null) {
            out.add(isoMessage);
        } else {
            throw new ParseException("Can't parse ISO8583 message", 0);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.info("exceptionss");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: *but I faced and exception of StringIndexOutOfBoundsException.* [details](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/17-errors)
please

Comment: `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 0, end 174, length 163
        at java.base/java.lang.String.checkBoundsBeginEnd(String.java:3319)
        at java.base/java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1874)
        at com.solab.iso8583.parse.LllvarParseInfo.parse(LllvarParseInfo.java:70)
        at com.solab.iso8583.MessageFactory.parseMessage(MessageFactory.java:575)
        at com.solab.iso8583.MessageFactory.parseMessage(MessageFactory.java:366)
.
.
.
`

Comment: Basically you should have the length of the buffer at the beginning of the message (This may vary between network schema), try to use it and read only the bytes needed

Comment: I am getting the length of the buffer by `byteBuf.readableBytes()` and it works for English characters, but gives me the exception with Arabic/Persian characters.

Comment: ```System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(bytes));```  gives what?

Comment: [1, 31, 49, 49, 49, 48, 116, 48, 0, 0, 14, -127, -128, 0, 49, 54, 57, 48, 48, 52, 50, 48, 48, 55, 51, 48, 49, 49, 48, 53, 53, 52, 53, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 53, 52, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 53, 52, 48, 48, 48, 49, 52, 53, 48, 56, 48, 50, 50, 48, 57, 49, 55, 48, 56, 53, 50, 51, 51, 53, 52, 54, 57, 48, 49, 49, 52, 53, 48, 56, 48, 50, 57, 55, 51, 52, 54, 48, 48, 48, 65, 72, 71, 32, 80, 79, 83, 49, 49, 55, 52, 48, 48, 50, 48, 48, 51, 53, 49, 49, 48, 48, 52, 48, 48, 51, 48, 48, 57, 48, 50, 53, 48, 49, 50, 53, 52, 54, 57, 48, 49, 49, 52, 53, 48, 56, 48, 48, 51

Comment: ... ,51, 48, 48, 56, 48, 49, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 49, 48, 52, 52, 48, 48, 56, 48, 49, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 49, 48, 53, 57, 48, 49, 50, 53, 52, 54, 57, 48, 49, 49, 52, 53, 48, 56, 48, 56, 53, 48, 48, 48, 55, 49, 50, 51, 52, 48, 48, 48, 56, 53, 54, 48, 48, 56, 48, 49, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 49, 56, 53, 55, 48, 48, 53, 53, 52, 48, 48, 48, 56, 54, 48, 48, 51, 48, -40, -86, -40, -84, -40, -89, -40, -79, -40, -86, -37, -116, 32, -40, -83, -39, -123, -40, -78, -39, -121, 32, -40, -77, -39, -121, -37, -116, -39, -124, 56, 57, 56, 48, 49, 50, 57, 52, 57, 49, 54, 52, 51, 55, 50, 54, 56, 48, 48, 48, 48]

Comment: ```0ظ�ظ،ظ�ظ�ظ�� ظ­ع
ظ�ع ظ�ع�ع``` could be *something* like the end of that. Does that look feasible?

Comment: Yes, it is feasible but gives me the exception.

Comment: Well as you can see, that is only partially correct so you need a way of finding which bytes are *meant* to be text